# What restrictions on KML/KMZ upload exist in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am currently using the google maps api v3 to load kml files 
into my web application. The file I am having trouble with 
is a KML which is 274 KB big. It will not load (uncompressed the 
file is about 8mb). If I take out elements from the file to shrink it, 
then i does load in my web app.

But when i use *http://maps.google.com/?q=http://myapp/kml/mykml.kmz, 
then the KML loads perfectly. 
If someone can shed some light on this it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: All KML/KMZ are passed through Google Servers - Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ) is only 3MB. http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html

Comment: ok so fetched file size would mean my kmz (274 kb) is within the limit? (not the 8mb kml i had before zip)

Comment: I have been having problem with the zooming on security code from my yahoo signing in. What can I do to minimize the zoom or remove the zoom in other for me to login to my yahoo email account through my blackberry phone

Answer (score 2):

Im not so sure on the restrictions in the API but I would imagine a file that size would render extremely slow. An option could be to import your KML file into google fusion tables and then query it using the GM API. The filesize limit is 100mb though, when importing to google fusion tables.

Comment: workaround, you can have multiple fusion tables linked to one map.

Comment: thanks for the quick response,I have in fact considered fusion tables, my concern was that i dont want to make the kml/kmz publicly accessable, would i be able to control who has access to this data?

Answer (score 1):

274 Kb for a KMZ should not be a problem.
However Google caches your kml file. So if it was not correctly placed or corrupted it will not show. A handy trick to get Google to refresh your file is to change the url in a way that it points to the same file but looks like a new one to Google.

try:

```
http://your_url/your_path/your_filename.kmz?123
```

This is especially handy if you want a new kml to refresh immediately on your site. Of course you have to change the argument ?123 in some other number to refresh again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response ive done the refresh and its still not showing in my web app. but when i downloaded the kml through the url it diplays 100% in google earth

Answer (score 0):

If your server takes a while to respond (more than a few seconds), Google will abort fetching. You could check that. I don't know if that would affect the KML search on maps.google.com.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, this might very well be my problem, could you please let me know how i could test this, ive tested the code from running it locally on my computer as well as published to my iis server(where the kmz file is also located) and both ways failed to load the kmz

Comment: If you open up Firebug in Firefox, or Developer Tools in Chrome, and go to the network panel (net panel in Firebug), you'll see a 500 Internal Server Error on for a request to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/KmlOverlayService.GetOverlays?1s[your url]&callback=[whatever]&token=[whatever]. There's more on this issue at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-maps-js-api-v3%2Ff1JLYUSOEHc%2Fdiscussion .